# How to convert List<Article> to List<IArticle> in C# 3.5

Tags: c#

Code ex:

```
public Interface IArticle
{
    int cid{get;set;}
    string Name{get;set;}
    string Content{get;set;}
    ...
}
public Class Article:IArticle
{
   public int cid{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public string Content{get;set;}
   public string Extension{get;set;}
    ...
}

/*
ArticleBiz.GetArticles(int cid) is select some items from database,return type:List<Article>
*/
List<IArticle> articleList=ArticleBiz.GetArticles(2).FindAll(p=>p.cid==cid)
```

Exception:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.List<Zm.Models.Article>'
to
    'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Zm.Models.IArticle>'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Question: I don't want to change the return type to `List<IArticle>` in the `GetArticles(..)` method. How can I change the code to convert `List<Article>` to `List<IArticle>` successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that assigning a List to a List doesn't work is because then you could do the following:

```
class CrazyArticle : IArticle { ... }

List<Article> articles = ...
List<IArticle> iarticles = articles; // this is not actually legal

iarticles.Add(new CrazyArticle());
// now either things should crash because we tried to add CrazyArticle to a List<Article>,
// or we have violated type safety because the List<Article> has a CrazyArticle in it!
```

There are at least two options here:

(1) You can build a new list of type IArticle with the LINQ Cast<> operator:

```
var iarticles = articles.Cast<IArticle>().ToList();
```

(2) You can change to returning IEnumerable:

```
// this is legal because IEnumerable<T> is declared as IEnumerable<out T>
IEnumerable<IArticle> iarticles = articles;
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my approach:

```
IList<IArticle> articles = new List<Article>().Cast<IArticle>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ:

```
List<IArticle> articleList = ArticleBiz
    .GetArticles(2)
    .Where(p => p.cid == cid)
    .Cast<IArticle>()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
List<IArticle> articleList = ArticleBiz.GetArticles(2).Where(p => p.cid == cid) 
                                       .Select(x => (IArticle)x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own implicit cast.

```
public static implicit operator IArticle(Article article)
{
    return article;
}
```

Another solution is to write an explicit cast operator

```
///No need for an explicit cast though.
public static explicit operator IArticle(Article article)
{
    return (IArticle)article;
}
```

But could you tell me why you are returning Articles from the database instead of the IArticle object?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, Select can help you.

```
List<IArticle> articleList = ArticleBiz.GetArticles(2).FindAll(p => p.cid == cid)
                                       .Select(x => x as IArticle).ToList()
```